# altering a substring of a string Java

Tags: string, replace, expression, substring

how to alter a substring of a string using replaceAll()
for example using the regular expression "1[a-z]+" (split with "X") and the code:

```
"this is an example 1one"
```

should produce:

```
"this is an example 1Xone"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "this is an example 1one";
    str = str.replaceAll("1([a-z]+)", "1X$1");
    System.out.println(str);
  }
}
```